# phonegap app connected to node server by socket.io works on browser but not in app

Tags: ios, node.js, cordova, socket.io

i setted up a node server, this sends data via socket.io to the clients and use that in a phonegap projekt,

it works fine when i test it in browsers & mobile browsers but it does not work when i build a ios app which i run in the emulator,

part of node server code:

```
define(['node-static','http'],function (Static,Http) {
return FileServer = function (server) {

    var httpFileServer = new Static.Server('./phonegap/www');

    Http.createServer(function (request, response) {
        request.addListener('end', function () {
            httpFileServer.serve(request, response);
        }).resume();
    }).listen(server.fileServerHTTPport,"0.0.0.0");

    return {
        // exampleVariable : function() {return exampleVariable},
        // exampleFunction : exampleFunction
    }
} });
```

index.html phonegap

```
... <script src="js/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://'+document.location.hostname+':54321');
   socket.on('display', function (data) {
      console.log(data.color);
      $("h1").text( data.color.h );
});
</script></head>
<body><h1> hello world</h1> ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out, i have to use the devices default localhost ip,
so for example in ios: 127.0.0.1

```
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:54321');
```

Comment: But how will it connect to your server if you say localhost, when you have you have your nodejs server running somewhere else.

Comment: I don't exactly know, but in this case it worked i think because of the same wifi network,

Comment: using 127.0.0.1 works, because this is your local IP and you are running in the emulator. If you run on a real iPhone, you will not be able to connect back to your dev. machine if you use this IP address. You'd rather have to use a "real" IP address such as 192.168.178.xxx. Note that window.location.hostname == '' when you open your app in Cordova/Phonegap, while it has a different value (such as 'localhost') if you open the app in the browser.